# abort() called using std::regex to validate URL

Tags: c++, regex, validation, c++11

```
#include  <iostream>      
#include  <string>    
#include <regex>    
using namespace std;   

int main ()
{        

  if (std::regex_match ("http://www.google.com", std::regex("(http|https):\/\/(\w+\.)*(\w*)\/([\w\d]+\/{0,1})+")))    
    std::cout << "valid URL \n";  
  std::cout << std::endl;     
  return 0;

}
```

its compiling with the warnings ,but when I executed it  gives

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'

  what():  regex_error
```

Aborted (core dumped)

what I should Do?

Comment: Do you use a C++11 compatible compiler?

Comment: Can you paste "the warnings"?

Comment: test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:9:61: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\/' [enabled by default]
test.cpp:9:61: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\w' [enabled by default]
test.cpp:9:61: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\d' [enabled by default]
test.cpp:9:61: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\/' [enabled by default]
abc@abc-abc:/exports/Documents_referred$ ./output 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
Aborted (core dumped)
abc@abc-abc:/exports/Documents_referred$

Comment: o/p is  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: if the code is working on your machine?

Comment: can anybody please help with this..I am stuck with the error from 2 weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **[cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.9.4/index.html)**:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/network/uri.hpp>

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::string address = "http://www.google.com";
    boost::network::uri::uri uri_(address);
    if ( !boost::network::uri::valid(uri_) )
    {
        // error
        std::cout << "not valid" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "valid" << std::endl;

    std::string host = boost::network::uri::host(uri_); 
    std::string port = boost::network::uri::port(uri_); 
    std::string scheme = boost::network::uri::scheme(uri_);

    return 0;
}
```

How to build (cpp-netlib is in /root/cpp-netlib-0.9.4/ in my case):

```
g++ main.cpp -L/root/cpp-netlib-0.9.4/libs/network/src/ -I/root/cpp-netlib-0.9.4/ -o main -lcppnetlib-uri -lboost_system
```

Comment: I got cc1plus: error: /root/cpp-netlib-0.9.4/: Permission denied

Comment: You have to have the boost library installed and cpp-netlib must also be downloaded and built. http://cpp-netlib.org/0.9.4/getting_started.html

Comment: Install Boost library first. `sudo apt-get install libboost-dev`

Comment: Make a folder. Download cpp-netlib using `wget https://github.com/downloads/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib-0.9.4.zip` Unzip it and build using manual. Change  /root/cpp-netlib-0.9.4/ path to an actual. Compile your main.cpp again.

Comment: will this program validate an url with ip address,rather than domain name?

Comment: Yes, it will. You may extract parts `std::string host = boost::network::uri::host(uri_);` `std::string port = boost::network::uri::port(uri_);` `std::string scheme = boost::network::uri::scheme(uri_);`

Comment: when I tried  sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: There is a better place to help you with your system configuration. Go to http://superuser.com/ and ask a question about the Boost library and cpp-netlib installation problem.

Comment: When I enter std::string address = "http://123.34.23.56:6662626"; then also its saying valid URL while its not valid bcoz port num must be lass than 65536.

Comment: when I execute aptitude search libboost I dint get network/uri anything like that how can i can do it?

Comment: cpp-netlib is not a part of the boost library yet, but it uses boost.

Comment: I followed the procedure at http://cpp-netlib.org/0.9.4/getting_started.html#getting-started and its working fine but now ,If cppnet-lib is not the part of boost  ,I want to add it to my project how I can do it? when I copied the cpp-netlib-0.9.4/boost/network  to /usr/include/boost/ ,then I copied network.hpp and mime.hpp to /usr/include/boost ,when tried to compile my project it's not compiling its giving error  fatal error: boost/network/uri/detail/parse_uri.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: how to resolve it   Boost version: 1.46.1

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_network

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.

Answer (score 3):

The warnings that you are ignoring are probably telling you what the problem is.

By looking at the pattern, you have not properly escaped the pattern string.

Properly escaping the pattern string to use '\' to escape the backslash will solve the problem. Otherwise, the compiler is tring to interpret the character that follows the un-escaped backslash into a string control character.

```
std::regex("(http|https)://(\\w+.)(\\w)/([\\w\\d]+/{0,1})+")
```

Comment: its giving the same problem .the problem is with  [ and ] in regex how to remove it.?

Comment: Unfortunally this only a part of the problem, it still thows: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error

Comment: Or use C++11 raw strings: `std::regex(R"((http|https)://(\w+.)(\w)/([\w\d]+/{0,1})+)");`

Comment: after using above sentence also I am getting terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
Aborted (core dumped) on executing